# Appending a tuple into another tuple python

Tags: python

I have a list of `a = [("apple", "red"), ("pear", "green"), ("orange", "orange"), ("banana", "yellow"), ("tomato", "red")]`

I want to iterate through this list and if `a[1] = "red"`, how do I append the whole tuple `("tomato", "red")` and `("apple", "red")` such that it will appear in `b=[]` list as `b = [("tomato", "red), ("apple", "red")]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
b = [tup for tup in a if tup[1] == "red"]
print(b)
[('apple', 'red'), ('tomato', 'red')]
```

Comment: what if I want both the colour `"red"` and `"green"` to be appended into the tuple list?

Comment: @KimSuYu `if tup[1] in ('red', 'green')`

Answer (score 1):

Just append the tuple:

```
In [19]: a = [("apple", "red"), ("pear", "green"), ("orange", "orange"), ("banana", "yellow"), ("tomato", "red"), ('avocado','green')]

In [20]: reds = []

In [21]: for pair in a:
    ...:     if pair[1] == 'red':
    ...:         reds.append(pair)
    ...:

In [22]: reds
Out[22]: [('apple', 'red'), ('tomato', 'red')]
```

However, it seems to me you might be looking for a grouping, which could conveniently be represented with a *dictionary of lists*:

```
In [23]: grouper = {}

In [24]: for pair in a:
    ...:     grouper.setdefault(pair[1], []).append(pair)
    ...:

In [25]: grouper
Out[25]:
{'green': [('pear', 'green'), ('avocado', 'green')],
 'orange': [('orange', 'orange')],
 'red': [('apple', 'red'), ('tomato', 'red')],
 'yellow': [('banana', 'yellow')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I second the list comprehension, you can even do it with the names of the things.

```
b = [(fruit, color) for fruit, color in a if color == "red"]
```

or if you wanna do it in a loop:

```
b = []
for fruit, color in a:
   if color == "red":
       b.append((fruit, color))
```

or if you wanna do multiple variations:

```
def fruitByColor(ogList, filterList):
    return ([(fruit, color) for fruit, color in ogList 
             if color in filterList])

fruitByColor(a, ["green", "red"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of tuples with colors as keys and values as list of fruits as follows:

```
colors={}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][1] not in colors:
        colors[a[i][1]]=[a[i][0]]
    else:
        colors[a[i][1]].append(a[i][0])
```

*Output:*

```
{'green': ['pear'],
'orange': ['orange'],
'red': ['apple', 'tomato'],
'yellow': ['banana']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b = []
a = [("apple", "red"), ("pear", "green"), ("orange", "orange"), ("banana", "yellow"), ("tomato", "red")]
if a[1][1] == "red":
    b.append(("tomato", "red"))
    b.append(("apple", "red"))
print(b)
```

The `a[1][1]` accesses the second element in the array `a` and the second element of the tuple in that element